# Zsh prompt with current working directory

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

In bash I have my PROMPT set like so

`PS1="$(scutil --get ComputerName) \W\\$ "`

Where I only see the computer name and only the name of the current directory that I am in, not the full path and a $ sign.

`my-computer my-folder$`

My question is how can I set up my zsh prompt to be just like the bash one. I've been googling around, but the solutions I've found are not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you tried `PS1='\h \W\$ '` in `bash`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

See the **EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES** and **SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES** sections of the `zsh` manual page at `man zshmisc`.

This prompt string, `PS1='%m %1d$ '`, displays the machine name (`%m`) and the trailing component of the current path (`%1d`).

Comment: man page are always good help indeed :) using %~ to have prompt with home replaced by ~.

Answer (score 36):

### The best version of the combinations that works for me is this:

`PS1='%n@%m %~$ '`

%n is the user logged in

%m is the machine name

%~ gives the path relative to HOME, if path begins with HOME.

#### This is how it is for me:

[image: This is how it is for me]

The man page has more info. I tried to put in simpler terms here.! :D

Comment: Thanks! This is the true equivalent to the bash version. The other answer (%1d) only shows the lowest hierarchy in the directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

To show only the directory followed by a `%` sign, e.g.:

```
/usr/local%
```

Put the following in `~/.zshrc` (create the file if it doesn't exist):

```
PROMPT='%~%# '
```

`%~` displays the current directory, but your HOME directory will be replaced by a `~`:

```
/usr/local% cd
~% pwd
/Users/7stud
% cd erlang_programs 
~/erlang_programs% pwd
/Users/7stud/erlang_programs
~/erlang_programs% cd /opt/local
/opt/local%
```

That keeps the prompt short and sweet.

The docs say that `%#` will display a `%` sign, but if you are using privileges, e.g. with the `su` command, then it will display a `#` sign.  When I use `sudo`, it still displays a `%` sign.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion

```
PS1='%~: '
```

anywhere in ~/.zshrc is the cleanest / simplest.

```
PS1='%~ $: '
```

is also pretty good.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the accepted answer from eight years ago?

Comment: It's structurally / basically the same, but provides two shortcuts for people who want the most simple / minimal exact code to make the Zsh prompt look like bash